# Rewriting mail() on a server that doesn't support php's mail() function?

Tags: smtp, email

I've just shifted to WebFaction and didn't realise its mail() function doesn't do anything. WebFaction disable it for shared servers. Doh! The problem is my receipts are dispatched via mail() as well as some extra stuff I included to autotically send the order to the supplier.

I'm using wp-ecommerce plugin and all the reciept sending is done via what appears to come from a script more complex than I can understand and change to use something other than mail().

Is there an easy workaround you know of? Like something that rewrites the mail() function perhaps? I found http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/#configure-smtp hoping it would do the job, and while Wordpress is now sending via this, wp-ecommerce isn't affected. sad

Any ideas? Quick fixes?

Comment: I just found this out today actually... I didn't realise that they didn't have mail set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented SwiftMailer (swiftmailer.org)

And also come across http://www.callum-macdonald.com/code/wp-mail-smtp/ which overrides the default wp_mail() function.